# Injectivity and Compositionality

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

> Give an example of two functions $f$ and $g$ for which $f$ is injective, but $g\circ f$ is not.

I suspect this will do:

$$f(x) = x~\text{and}~g(x)=1$$

This is the image which leads me to this conclusion:

\begin{eqnarray}
      & \vdots          & \\
1 & \longrightarrow & 1 \\
&&&\searrow \\
&&&~~~~1\\
&&& \nearrow\\
2&\longrightarrow&2 \\
&\vdots&&
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: This doesn't make any sense... My example I mean. Wait... Maybe it is right...

Comment: What part doesn't make sense? (Also, there seems to be a problem with your image.)

Comment: your example is right..but you should express your doubts so the others can help you where you got stuck

Answer (score 0):

Your example is right.
$f(x)=x$ is injective , can you see why?

Now $g(f(x))=1$  for every $x$. Can a constant function be injective?

Remember the definition of injective function: a funtion $f$ defined on $A$ is injetive iff $\forall a,b \in A, \;\; f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b$